# Run aws_s3 task on remote with environment credentials from executor

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

I would like to upload a file from remote host to a s3 bucket but with  credentials from the local execution environment. Is that possible?

```
- name: Upload file
   host: '{{target}}'
   gather_facts : False
   tasks:
   - name: copy file to bucket
     become: yes
     aws_s3:
       bucket={{bucket_name}}
       object={{filename}}
       src=/var/log/{{ filename }}
       mode=put
```

Is there any switch, option I could use?. The best would be something like that:

```
AWS_PROFILE=MyProfile ansible-playbook upload_file.yml -e target=somehost -e bucket_name=mybucket -e filename=myfile
```

So I could specify the profile from my own local `.aws/config` file.

Obviously when running the playbook like this:

```
ansible-playbook upload_file.yml -e target=somehost -e bucket_name=mybucket -e filename=myfile
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TASK [copy file to bucket] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
fatal: [somehost]: FAILED! => {"boto3_version": "1.7.50", "botocore_version": "1.10.50", "changed": false, "msg": "Failed while looking up bucket (during bucket_check) adverity-trash.: Unable to locate credentials"}
```

But when I try the following:

```
 AWS_ACCESS_KEY=<OWN_VALID_KEY> AWS_SECRET_KEY=<OWN_VALID_SECRET> ansible-playbook upload_file.yml -e target=somehost -e bucket_name=mybucket -e filename=myfile
```

It's the same error.

Ansible `v2.6`

Comment: have you think about pushing the credentials in a file to the target from the executor at the beginning of the play and use that file to source environment when module `aws_s3` is run. Nevertheless the question is lack some technical details and you are supposed to have some code to show and your failure for the question to be valid. Thanks

Comment: @baptistemm I've the added the failures I'm getting and more examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He're a satisfying solution to my problem.

With help of @einarc and the ansible hostvars I was able to achieve a remote upload capability with credentials comming from local environment
The facts gathering was not necessary and I used delegate_to to do some tasks locally. Everything is in one playbook

```
- name: Transfer file
  hosts: '{{ target }}'
  gather_facts : False
  tasks:
  - name: Set AWS KEY ID
    set_fact: aws_key_id="{{ lookup('env','AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') }}"
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  - name: Set AWS SECRET
    set_fact: aws_secret_key="{{ lookup('env','AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  - name: Get AWS KEY ID
    set_fact: aws_key_id={{hostvars[inventory_hostname]['aws_key_id']}}
  - name: Get AWS SECRET KEY
    set_fact: aws_secret_key={{hostvars[inventory_hostname]['aws_secret_key']}}
  - name: ensure boto is available
    become: true
    pip: name=boto3 state=present
  - name: copy file to bucket
    become: yes
    aws_s3:
      aws_access_key={{aws_key_id}}
      aws_secret_key={{aws_secret_key}}
      bucket=my-bucket
      object={{filename}}
      src=/some/path/{{filename}}
      mode=put
```

Bonus: 
I found a way to not explicitly put the aws credentials in command line.

I've used the following bash wrapper to get the credentials from config file with the help of `aws-cli`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=`aws configure get aws_access_key_id --profile $1`
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=`aws configure get aws_secret_access_key --profile $1`

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID \ 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY \
ansible-playbook transfer_to_s3.yml -e target=$2 -e filename=$3
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is : How do I pass environment variables from one host to another. The answer is in hostvars. Feel free to do your own search on hostvars but this'll give a general idea: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-see-all-the-inventory-vars-defined-for-my-host

Step 1: GATHER the AWS environment credentials from localhost(where you're running ansible from). IMPORTANT: Make sure to set gather_facts to TRUE otherwise the lookup Jinja2 plugin won't find the keys(assuming you've set them up as environment variables in localhost).

```
- name: Set Credentials
   host: localhost
   gather_facts : true
   tasks:
   - name: Set AWS KEY ID
     set_fact: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="{{ lookup('env','AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') }}"
   - name: Set AWS SECRET
     set_fact: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="{{ lookup('env','AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
```

Step 2: Import those environment variables from localhost using set_fact and the hostvars Jinja2 plugin.

Step 3: Use the environment variables on {{target}}

Step 2 and 3 are put together below.

```
- name: Upload file
   host: '{{target}}'
   gather_facts : False
   tasks:
   - name: Get AWS KEY ID
     set_fact: aws_key_id={{hostvars['localhost']['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']}}
   - name: Get AWS SECRET KEY
     set_fact: aws_secret_key={{hostvars['localhost']['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']}}
   - name: copy file to bucket
     become: yes
     aws_s3:
       bucket={{bucket_name}}
       object={{filename}}
       src=/var/log/{{ filename }}
       mode=put
       aws_access_key='{{aws_key_id}}'
       aws_secret_key='{{aws_secret_key}}'
```

Comment: does the lookup happen on the executor of the target ?

Comment: Delegate allows you to move in between inventory hosts to perform complimentary tasks. This actually gives me an idea. One sec as I modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have the error because the environment variables are not propagated to the remote host when the playbook is run.

As the documentation [explains](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/aws_s3_module.html) (bottom of the page) this possible to use environment variables or boto profiles with `aws_s3` but they should exist on the host that perform the push.

so what I would do is

- put the AWS variables into a variable file
- create a boto profile file to the target generated from a template
- launch the `aws_s3` module.

## vars/aws.yml

```
---
aws_access_key_id: 24d32dsa24da24sa2a2ss
aws_access_key: 2424dadsxxx
```

## templates/boto.j2

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = {{ aws_access_key_id }}
aws_secret_access_key = {{ aws_access_key }}
```

## playbook.yml

```
- name: Upload file
   host: '{{ target }}'
   gather_facts : False
   vars_files:
     - vars/aws.yml

   tasks:
     - name: push boto template
       template:
         src: boto.j2
         dest: {{ ansible_user_dir }}/.boto
         mode: 0400

     - name: copy file to bucket
       become: yes
       aws_s3:
         bucket={{bucket_name}}
         object={{filename}}
         src=/var/log/{{ filename }}
         mode=put
```

**ps:**

- I never use boto profile hence I'm not sure how it works, so my code is juste based on educated guess.
- It seems the aws_s3 [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/aws_s3_module.html) is unclear about the version of boto to use, as link is pointing to boto2 but deps are saying boto3
- I'm not sure why you need to become for `aws_s3` task