# Are env vars safe when using an ansible shell command on remote?

Tags: shell, ansible

Given this task for `ansible`:

```
- name: Get file from S3
  ansible.builtin.shell: "aws s3 cp {{ path }} ."  
  args:
    chdir: "/home/{{ user }}"
  environment:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') }}"
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
```

Is using these AWS secret vars, set in the control hosts's environment, safe on the remote machine?

I guess it is, at `ansible` is using `ssh` for connections, but couldn't find any definitive information for this.

Comment: At first glance, I would consider safer to use the [relevant module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_s3_module.html) rather than the shell and set the credentials in the module parameters.

Comment: The reason that I was going via `shell` is that that module is a nightmare to get working. First it complains about all the pythons and the botos module. Now that I finally got that working, it can't load my `~/.aws/credentials` from the controller host, nor the `~/.boto` file. Want to avoid having to store such files on destination.

I will end up having to do the same as above which is to pass env vars and set  them explicitly via `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') }}"` - so the question becomes the same, how are those env vars transmitted, is that safe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744030/run-aws-s3-task-on-remote-with-environment-credentials-from-executor/51777074 looks like tackling the same problem. They are using env vars as well. Doesn't seem like there is away around that.